# algorithm to find area of largest sub-array(rectangle) consisting entirely of 1's

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

There is a 2D binary array (2D array of `0` and `1`) where `m` rows and `n` columns; give an efficient algorithm to find area of largest sub-array (rectangle) consisting entirely of `1`s.

```
public int findMaxRectangleArea(int[][] A,int m,int n);
```

Can someone please help me with the algorithm part?

Comment: are you in an interview?

Comment: A similar question has been posted for `C#`, with a slightly different condition (equal sums for 0 and 1). You will find the pseudo code in the accepted answer: [Largest submatrix with equal no of 1's and 0's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698298/largest-submatrix-with-equal-no-of-1s-and-0s).

Comment: Why all the language tags? Do you have to provide a solution in these? You'd might want to tag `language-agnostic` instead

Comment: looks like someone's digital logic design homework (k-map)

Comment: http://www.drdobbs.com/database/the-maximal-rectangle-problem/184410529

Comment: Yes sir it's my interview question. **Mr ogzd**

Comment: Then you shouldn't get the job until you've done more studying.

Comment: leave it i did it my own way. thanx to all

Comment: Meh about this being closed, but who would vote to delete? Are algorithms really off-topic here? Really?

Answer (score 2):

I'd try an approach like this:

Iterate left to right row by row until you find a `0`.

This `0` may already identify two rectangles of `1`s:

- all rows above it
- from the top left to the position to the left of the `0`

One of them is bigger, remember it.

[image: First step]

Then recursively descend into the three unknown sectors (two of them partially unknown) that may still contain a rectangle bigger than what you have already found:

[image: Second step]

Make sure you don't iterate over the known rows again, that's redundant.

I believe this solution can look at each field at most twice (where a recursion step's sectors overlap), so it should run in θ(x*y).

Comment: not quite there yet... there is a merging step that you omitted that is not trivial.  so you've divided the problem after finding a 0, but then after recursively solving the smaller pieces, you need to merge...

Comment: Is the merging step really not trivial? If a solution is in smaller pieces, it's entirely contained in one of them, so the whole solution is just the greatest of the four. If I'm wrong, please show an example.

Comment: i don't know but it's not listed... trivial or not is subjective.  my point is the solution is incomplete.  i haven't thought about it...

Answer (score 0):

It all depends ion how large your smallest array dimension is. If it's smaller than the maximum word size on your target platform, you could make your array into a 1D array of bitmaps and use a series of sliding bitmask windows to find the rectangle.